# Difference-in-difference with fixed effects

Tags: econometrics

I am estimating the following DID model:

$$
 Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Treatment}_{i} +\beta_2 \text{Post}_{t} + \beta_3 \text{Treatment}_{i} \cdot \text{Post}_{t} + \varepsilon_{it} \\
\text{where} \\
\text{Treatment}_{i} = \cases{1\;\text{ if unit } i \text{ treated }\\
0 \text{ else }} \\
\text{Post}_{t} = \cases{1\;\text{ if time } t \text{ is post-treatment }\\
0 \text{ else }} \\
$$

My understanding is that the variable "treatment" is time-invariant. However, a journal reviewer asked me to run a fixed-effects model. I do not understand how this can be done. If treatment is time-invariant, then it is not possible to run a fixed-effects analysis, right?

Comment: The reviewer needs to provide more information. DID models *are* fixed effects models. At least for some definitions of fixed effects.

Comment: It would require that you have actual panel data with unique identifiers. In the simple 2period model with no additional controls variables (like your equation here) the estimated effects are numerically exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have panel data. I am in finance and work on data with firm-year observations. My model actually has control variables. A colleague of mine suggests that I drop the treatment variable and run a fixed-effects analysis because what we focus on is the coefficient of the interaction term.

Comment: @Financiality1, from your original question: why do you say that treatment is time invariant if your DiD model suggests otherwise?  From your comment from 5th March, what "interaction term" do you mean?  The Treatment*After interaction term?

Comment: I have re-written the model to make the notation clearer -- please ensure that this does not obscure/change any essential detail in the question.